# Python webbrowser open function not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to open an online link such as: "https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/spicylambburgerswith_67593"

```
import webbrowser as wb
def open_site(url):
    wb.open_new_tab(url)
```

When I call the function, I receive the following error:

```
realpath: 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/spicylambburgerswith_67593': No such file or directory
```

Can I not open online links? If so is there a way to open it?

Comment: You need to share your full code's [mre]. Because for instance, a big important question is, how are you _calling_ `open_site`? If you're doing something like `browser = wb.get(f'windows-default-file://{browser_path}')` and then `browser.open_new_tab(url)`, you have to make sure `browser_path` is valid. You need to ensure you have a default web browser set on your system. The webbrowser module relies on your system having a default browser to open URLs.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code and it runs fine on my machine. Can you share how you are calling `open_site`?

Comment: This code **defines** the `open_site()` function but does not actually **call** it, so your actual code must be different from what you have shown.  Please show your real full code.